# Calculate first-order term of the $S$-matrix for the $\phi^{4}$ theory

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, perturbation-theory, s-matrix-theory, wick-theorem

Before I ask a question, I will start with a small introduction.

I want to evaluate the $S$-matrix order-by-order in an expansion in small $\lambda$ for a $2  \rightarrow 2$ scattering in $\phi^{4}$ theory.

The initial and finale states are:
$$|i\rangle = \sqrt{4\omega_{\mathbf{p}_{1}}\omega_{\mathbf{p}_{2}}}a^{\dagger}_{\mathbf{p}_{1}}a_{\mathbf{p}_{2}}^{\dagger}|0\rangle \equiv |\mathbf{p}_{1}, \mathbf{p}_{2}\rangle$$
$$|f\rangle = \sqrt{4\omega_{\mathbf{p}_{3}}\omega_{\mathbf{p}_{4}}}a^{\dagger}_{\mathbf{p}_{3}}a_{\mathbf{p}_{4}}^{\dagger}|0\rangle \equiv |\mathbf{p}_{3}, \mathbf{p}_{4}\rangle$$

The Hamiltonian density is:
$$\mathcal{H}_{I} = \frac{\lambda}{4!}\phi^{4}$$

I want to evaluate the $S$-matrix order-by-order in an expansion in small $\lambda$:
$$\langle f|S|i\rangle = \langle \mathbf{p}_{3}, \mathbf{p}_{4}| T\left\{ \exp\left(-i \int d^{4}x\mathcal{H}_{I} \right)\right\}|\mathbf{p}_{1}, \mathbf{p}_{2}\rangle$$

$$ = \langle \mathbf{p}_{3}, \mathbf{p}_{4}|\mathbf{p}_{1}, \mathbf{p}_{2}\rangle - i\frac{\lambda}{4!}\int d^{4}x\langle \mathbf{p}_{3}, \mathbf{p}_{4}|T\left\{\phi^{4}\left(x\right) \right\}|\mathbf{p}_{1}, \mathbf{p}_{2}\rangle + \text{higher order terms}$$

$$ = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \mathcal{S}_{n}$$

Note: $\mathcal{S}_{n}$ denotes the sum of all terms of order $\lambda^{n}$.

At order $\lambda$, I need to evaluate: $$\langle \mathbf{p}_{3}, \mathbf{p}_{4}|T\left\{\phi^{4}\left(x\right) \right\}|\mathbf{p}_{1}, \mathbf{p}_{2}\rangle$$

I am going to use the following notation: $\phi_{x} \equiv \phi\left(x\right)$.

Applying Wick's theorem gives:
$$\langle \mathbf{p}_{3}, \mathbf{p}_{4}|N\left\{\phi_{x}\phi_{x}\phi_{x}\phi_{x} + \text{all contractions}\right\}|\mathbf{p}_{1}, \mathbf{p}_{2}\rangle$$

If I am not mistaken, there should be 9 terms for the term "all contractions".

The normal ordered product contain the following type of terms:
$$\overbrace{\phi_{x}\phi_{x}}\overbrace{\phi_{x}\phi_{x}} \quad \overbrace{\phi_{x}\phi_{x}}\phi_{x}\phi_{x} \quad \phi_{x}\phi_{x}\phi_{x}\phi_{x}$$

I am not sure if it is possible to use contraction symbol without using a package. For now, I use the command overbrace as contraction symbol.

The first term, $\overbrace{\phi_{x}\phi_{x}}\overbrace{\phi_{x}\phi_{x}}$, with all $\phi$-operators contracted with each other, corresponds to:

$$\mathcal{S}_{1}^{a} \equiv -i\frac{\lambda}{4!}\int d^4x  \langle \mathbf{p}_{3}, \mathbf{p}_{4}|\overbrace{\phi_{x}\phi_{x}}\overbrace{\phi_{x}\phi_{x}}|\mathbf{p}_{1}, \mathbf{p}_{2}\rangle$$

$$= -i\frac{\lambda}{4!} \langle \mathbf{p}_{3}, \mathbf{p}_{4}|\mathbf{p}_{1}, \mathbf{p}_{2}\rangle \times \int d^{4}x \Delta^{2}_{F}\left(x - x\right)$$

I want to evaluate:
$$\langle \mathbf{p}_{3}, \mathbf{p}_{4}|N\left\{\overbrace{\phi_{x}\phi_{x}}\phi_{x}\phi_{x}\right\}|\mathbf{p}_{1}, \mathbf{p}_{2}\rangle$$

Here starts the problem. The syllabus (not online material) says that: next, we consider the second term: $$\overbrace{\phi_{x}\phi_{x}}\phi_{x}\phi_{x}$$ in which two of the four $\phi$-operators are contracted.
The remaining two $\phi$-operators are contracted with two of the external particles
(one initial and one final). Finally, the last two external particles are contracted with each other.
This leads to:
[image]

Here is the problem, I assume that the other 3 terms are:
[image]
My first question is, is this correct?

My second question is, is the equation below also correct (if I understand correctly, the text and symbols seems to say the equation below)?
[image]

In case it is not correct, I don't understand why we start contracting scalar fields $\phi_{x}$ with states because we want to calculate $$\langle \mathbf{p}_{3}, \mathbf{p}_{4}|N\left\{\overbrace{\phi_{x}\phi_{x}}\phi_{x}\phi_{x}\right\}|\mathbf{p}_{1}, \mathbf{p}_{2}\rangle$$

Comment: What text are you following for this (if any)?

Comment: Don't ask us to check your work: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When applying Wick'e theorem to the "vacuum expectation values", any term with un-contracted operators gives zero. For instance,
$$\langle 0| N\{\overline{\phi(x)\phi(x)}\phi(x)\phi(x)\}|0\rangle=0$$
But when sandwiching between momentum states, it is not the case. Let's for example consider your last expression. Using  your first equation, it is written as
$$\sim\int d^4x\,\bigg(\prod_{i=1}^4\sqrt{2 \omega_{\textbf{p}_i}}\bigg)\,\langle 0| a_{\textbf{p}_4}a_{\textbf{p}_3}N\{\overline{\phi(x)\phi(x)}\phi(x)\phi(x)\}a_{\textbf{p}_1}^{\dagger}a_{\textbf{p}_2}^{\dagger}|0\rangle$$
It is easy to see that this matrix element is not zero. First we write it as
$$\sim D_F(x-x)\,\,\langle 0| a_{\textbf{p}_4}a_{\textbf{p}_3} N\{\phi(x)\phi(x)\}a_{\textbf{p}_1}^{\dagger}a_{\textbf{p}_2}^{\dagger}|0\rangle \\= D_F(x-x)\,\,\langle 0| a_{\textbf{p}_4}a_{\textbf{p}_3} \phi^{-}(x)\phi^{+}(x)a_{\textbf{p}_1}^{\dagger}a_{\textbf{p}_2}^{\dagger}|0\rangle\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,(1)$$
Now by use of
$$\phi^{+}(x)=\int \frac{d^3\textbf{q}_1}{(2\pi)^3}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\omega_{\textbf{q}_1}}} a_{\textbf{q}_1}e^{- i q_1.x}\\
\phi^{-}(x)=\int \frac{d^3\textbf{q}_2}{(2\pi)^3}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\omega_{\textbf{q}_2}}} a_{\textbf{q}_2}e^{ i q_2.x}\\
[a_{\textbf{p}_i},a^{\dagger}_{\textbf{p}_j}]=(2\pi)^3\delta^3(\textbf{p}_i-\textbf{p}_j)$$
The expression (1) above will contain (among other factors and integrals)
$$ \sim \langle 0| a_{\textbf{p}_4}\bigg([a_{\textbf{p}_3},a^{\dagger}_{\textbf{q}_2}]+a^{\dagger}_{\textbf{q}_2}a_{\textbf{p}_3}\bigg)\bigg([a_{\textbf{q}_1},a^{\dagger}_{\textbf{p}_1}]+a^{\dagger}_{\textbf{p}_1}a_{\textbf{q}_1}\bigg)a_{\textbf{p}_2}^{\dagger}|0\rangle\,\,\,\,\,\,\,(2)$$
Here there are four terms. Let's take the simplest one:
$$ 1^{st}\,\text{term}:\,\,\,\,\,[a_{\textbf{p}_3},a^{\dagger}_{\textbf{q}_2}]\,\,[a_{\textbf{q}_1},a^{\dagger}_{\textbf{p}_1}]\,\,\langle 0| a_{\textbf{p}_4}a_{\textbf{p}_2}^{\dagger}|0\rangle\\
=[a_{\textbf{p}_3},a^{\dagger}_{\textbf{q}_2}]\,\,[a_{\textbf{q}_1},a^{\dagger}_{\textbf{p}_1}]\,\,[a_{\textbf{p}_4},a^{\dagger}_{\textbf{p}_2}]$$
This represents exactly the contractions of the first term in https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pzb9J.png. Your next three terms corresponds to other terms in (2).

Note that sum of your  four terms should be finally multiplied with $D_F(x-x)$. Thus your last expression corresponds to a disconnected diagram.

In summary, to apply the Wick'e theorem  to the S-matrix elements, it should be noted that only those normal ordered interacting terms **may** contribute to connected diagrams  whose number of un-contarcted operators ($n_1$) is not less then the number of annihilation/creation operators in the final states ($n_2$): i.e., $n_1 \geq n_2$. Then, as shown above, the un-contarcted operators couple operators annihilating/creating the external frees states.
(in your example $n_1=2$ and $n_2=4$.)

Hope this helps.